If the ATC controller switches me to a visual approach midway through, does that still count as an instrument approach?
I was flying my 250-mile "long cross country" for my instrument rating as outlined in 14 CFR 61.65(d)(A)-(C). I had done two instrument approaches at two other airports, and my third approach was an LDA approach into a large Class B airport. We were cleared for the LDA approach, and then halfway through the approach, the controller said to us, "Cleared for the visual approach." I assume the controller did this out of habit and to expedite the flow of traffic at a busy airport. Does that mean that my third instrument approach is null and void and no longer counts as an instrument approach because it was changed by the controller to a visual approach? Do I now have to redo the entire 250-mile cross country because the controller switched me over to a visual approach halfway through an instrument approach, and therefore the instrument approach doesn't count?

Not helpful for you now, but just to be aware, you always have the option to decline the clearance for a visual approach.  The controller may not be happy, and if his options are either your approach becomes a visual, or he breaks you off of the training approach, or he has to make somebody else go around, well... you may get the "cancel approach clearance, fly runway heading, climb and maintain..." response. But even having reported the runway in sight, you aren't required to accept clearance for a visual approach.

@RalphJ I guess if he's on the LOC on final and the controller clears him visual, there's nothing stopping him from accepting the clearance and flying the LDA profile anyway, but to the question, for the purposes of meeting the legal training requirement, does the visual clearance invalidate it as a training/experience exercise?  Probably it's useful to mention that the approach to be flown is to meet training requirements during the arrival.

@JohnK  Yeah, fair point. If you have an uncontrolled airport and the safety pilot or CFII provides "vectors" around the pattern to intercept the ILS, does that count for currency purposes, even if ATC never said the words "cleared ILS runway XX"?  I'd assume so, but that's not my world.  We can log our Cat III approaches in VMC regardless of what ATC cleared us for as long as the switches & procedures in the cockpit are done (and since it's HUD & not autoland, we don't have to have the safety area protected). Interested in an authoritative answer to this.
